# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/signup/

Tags: python, django, django-registration

This error occurs when click on submit after form filling.I am tring to follow this tutorial but using a bootstrap templates for signup page `https://dev.to/coderasha/create-advanced-user-sign-up-view-in-django-step-by-step-k9m`

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def signup(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

app1/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

signup.html

```
<form role="form" action="signup"  method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
```

forms.html

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

Comment: pre is written in code by mistake

Comment: `action="signup"` add a leading slash to make this url absolute or leave simply blank attr `action=""` since you're already on signup page.

Comment: Following on from Ivan's comment, you can hardcode the absolute URL with `action="/signup/"`, or do `action="{% url 'signup' %}"` to avoid hardcoding the URL.